# How to determine whether my Android Google account credentials are valid?

Tags: android, credentials, android-c2dm, account

After an google account is updated, how to determine if credentials for that account are valid? I need to start C2DM communication only after the user enter valid credentials on his phone.  I need to check this in Android 2.2

Comment: You question is not very clear. Please give more details. C2DM doesn't really have to do anything with the user's credentials.

Comment: in order to use C2DM, you must have an google account on the device. After user sets the account on the device, he may change password for that account from web. After this, the password for that account on device is wrong. And how to detect this situation?

Answer (score 1):

To receive C2DM messages you are right that the device needs the user to be signed into their Google Account, but your app does not need access to the user's password. If the user ends up signed out of their Google Account on the device, then you will know because the C2DM registration will fail. I think that is the right way to check for this - that until you have received a successful registration response, assume the device is not able to use C2DM, and you could then block access to the app's UI, or show a message saying "Before using this app, please make sure you are signed into your Google account"

Comment: but how do I know that the c2dm registration fails because of the bad credentials? if there is an google account set on the device, the only remaining reason for registration to fail is bad credentials? I need to show two errors, one when is no account set on the device and another one when credentials are bad.

Comment: When you register the app on the device with C2DM, you do not provide authentication credentials, you simply provide the sender ID. This page shows details of the error code responses you can receive http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Comment: @gabi In general if you send a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER Intent, then you should receive a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION Intent. If there are bad credentials, rather than a registration_id, you should receive an appropriate error: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#handling_reg However, I believe I have found one instance in which this is not the case: http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/76ec1b3b5fdd8777